# Are the development tools in the Java Development Kit — namely, everything but the JRE — platform independent?

Tags: java

My current understanding is that the JDK is only considered platform-dependent because it includes a JRE and thus JVM, which is platform-dependent.

Among the JDK development tools, I know that javac is cross-platform, but what about the other tools?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the JDK tools have platform dependent code.  One obvious example is `jpackage` which generates platform dependent executables.

If you want to research this further, download the OpenJDK codebase and use `find` to find all of the directories with names like "windows", "unix" and "solaris".  Then figure out what uses / depends on the code in the respective directories.